# ¿Cómo crear un configurador para React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Me explico, necesito que mi proyecto en React, posea un archivo u alguna otra forma donde poder especificar la URL de una API, la idea es que el usuario final con el proyecto ya empaquetado y funcionando pueda especificar donde está el servidor sin tener que hacer un build.
Les agradezco la colaboración por adelantado.

Comment: [`process.env.REACT_APP_EL_API_LOCO`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

Comment: gracias, por tan pronta respuesta,

Comment: Si he probado las variables de entorno, pero estas pasan todos sus valores al proyecto en producción, después de hacer npm run build, necesito algo como un .ini o un .conf que sea permanente. Gracias ante todo

Comment: algo como un archivo [`.env`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) ?

Comment: mas o menos, como lo hace PHP, un config.php, y hay pones todas las variables las rutas, lo que se te ocurra, y le puedes dar el proyecto a cualquiera, para que cambie sus IP server por ejemplo sin tener que volver a hacer build de la aplicación

Comment: si es para web con incluir un javascript en el html debería bastar

Comment: Uuuh eso podría ser lo que hando buscando, deja insvestigar como pasar los datos desde ahí, o si me puedes dar un adelanto, gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para web, una variable global es tal vez todo lo que necesitas.

Para eso agregas un script en el html contenedor:

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/config.js"> </script>
```

public/config.js

```
window.__CONFIG__ = {
  apiURL:"https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?q&q=batata+park"
};
```

public/index.thml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

<!-- Cargamos configs -->  
  <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/config.js"> </script>

  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Al ser un objeto global, lo referencias directamente en la app por medio de `window.__CONFIG__`

src/App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";


function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(
      window.__CONFIG__.apiURL
    );
    const products = data.results;
    setProducts(products);
    console.log(
      window.__CONFIG__,
      products
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>apiURL: {window.__CONFIG__.apiURL}</p>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <p key={product.id}>{product.title}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo, esta es una solución perfecta, para lo que necesitaba.