# Blocked loading mixed active content “http://192.***.*.**:***/send-email”

Tags: angular, nodemailer

Tengo un frontend en Angular  subido a un host en Netlify

Es un formulario simple, que, luego de llenar los datos de usuario debe clickear en el botón de Enviar, y los datos se envían por correo electrónico a ciertos mails específicos...

El problema es que al hacerle click en el botón de enviar sale ese error en el inspector de Código, y los datos no se envían por correo electrónico...

este es mi archivo server.js :

```
    const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const multer = require('multer');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();

const limits = {
    fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MB (en bytes)
};
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { files: 5, fileSize: limits.fileSize }
});

app.post('/send-email', upload.array('files'), (req, res) => {

    const {
        nombre,
        apellido,
        dni,
        telefono,
        email,
        checkNombrePropio,
        nombreRepresentante,
        apellidoRepresentante,
        dniRepresentante,
        direccion,
        localidad,
        codigoPostal,
        direccionAlternativa,
        localidadAlternativa,
        codigoPostalAlternativo,
        nis,
        numeroDeCliente,
        descripcion,
        errorFacturacion,
        resarcimiento,
        suspencionSuministro,
        malaAtencionComercial,
        negativaConexion,
        inconvenienteTension,
        facturaFueraDeTermino
    } = req.body;

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: '*****.***.***.ar',
        port: 587,
        auth: {
            user: '****@*****.gov.ar',
            pass: '*******'
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    const destinatarios = '****@****.gov.ar, ****@**.gov.ar;


    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'administrador@eprern.gov.ar',
        to: destinatarios,
        subject: 'Nuevo formulario de Reclamos',
        html: `
        <h1><FONT color="#69b545"><u>Datos del USUARIO</u></FONT></h1>
        <br>
        


        <p><strong><u>Nombre:</u></strong> ${nombre}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Apellido:</u></strong> ${apellido}</p>
        <p><strong><u>DNI:</u></strong> ${dni}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Teléfono:</u></strong> ${telefono}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Email:</u></strong> ${email}</p>
      
        <p><strong><u>Actúa en Nombre Propio?:</u></strong> ${checkNombrePropio}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Nombre del Representante:</u></strong> ${nombreRepresentante}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Apellido del Representante:</u></strong> ${apellidoRepresentante}</p>
        <p><strong><u>DNI del Representante:</u></strong> ${dniRepresentante}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Dirección:</u></strong> ${direccion}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Localidad:</u></strong> ${localidad}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Código Postal:</u></strong> ${codigoPostal}</p>
        <br>
        <h3><FONT color="#69b545"><u>Coincide Direccion?  Si estos datos están repetidos ha marcado que sí</u></FONT></h3
        <p><strong><u>Dirección 2:</u></strong> ${direccionAlternativa}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Localidad 2:</u></strong> ${localidadAlternativa}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Código Postal 2:</u></strong> ${codigoPostalAlternativo}</p>
        <br><br>
        <p><strong><u>Nº NIS:</u></strong> ${nis}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Número de Cliente:</u></strong> ${numeroDeCliente}</p>
        <br>
        <p><strong><u>Descripción del RECLAMO:</u></strong> ${descripcion}</p>
        <br>
        <h1><FONT color="#69b545"><u>Tipología de Reclamo</u></FONT></h1>
        
        <p><strong><u>Error Facturación:</u></strong> ${errorFacturacion}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Resarcimiento:</u></strong> ${resarcimiento}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Suspensión Suministro:</u></strong> ${suspencionSuministro}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Mala Atención Comercial:</u></strong> ${malaAtencionComercial}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Negativa Conexión:</u></strong> ${negativaConexion}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Inconveniente Tensión:</u></strong> ${inconvenienteTension}</p>
        <p><strong><u>Factura Fuera de Termino/no recibidas:</u></strong> ${facturaFueraDeTermino}</p>
      
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>    
        <h3><FONT color="#612525">si dice true="Se tildó la casilla"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;si dice false="no se tildó la casilla"
        

    `,
        attachments: req.files.map((file) => ({
            filename: file.originalname,
            content: file.buffer
        }))
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).send('Error al enviar el correo electrónico');
        } else {
            console.log('Correo electrónico enviado: ' + info.response);
            res.status(200).send('Correo electrónico enviado con éxito');
        }
    });
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor escuchando en el puerto ${PORT}`);
});
```

Y desde Angular, tengo este servicio :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmailService {
  

  private baseUrl = 'http://***.***.*.***:****/send-email';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  sendEmailWithAttachment(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, formData);
  }
}
```

Yo ya tengo desplegado mi Frontend de Angular en un Hosting de Plesk....

El problema es que yo necesito desplegar mi server.js en un Windows Server 2019... y tengo desconocimiento de los certificados SSL, de si está la posibilidad de poder utilizar protocolos HTTPS en vez de HTTP, o de si es posible obtener certificados SSL gratuitos de algun sitio...

Pero yo segui una serie de pasos para desplegar mi server.js , los cuales fueron :

ejecutar el comando: pkg server.js -o NodemailerApp

esto me generó un archivo .exe el cual pegué en un directorio de mi windows server 2019 ... y lo ejecuté...

Probándolo desde mi maquina local, ejecutando mi proyecto angular con el comando: ng serve, dentro la misma red en donde está el servidor y  funciona el envío de mails... el problema es cuando despliego mi FrontEnd de Angular al hosting de Plesk. ya que ahora mi proyecto de Anugular en Plesk utiliza Protocolos HTTPS, y al darle click al botón de enviar apuntando a mi servidor me larga ese error mencionado en el título...

Pero como nunca me tocó un trabajo así soy nuevo en el tema, y voy aprendiendo sobre la marcha. Es por eso que tal vez estoy ignorando muchas cosas entre medio que están sucediendo...

Comment: en el frontend (angular) al `private baseUrl` fijate de cargarlo desde una variable de entorno, cosa de que en modo developer tome tu ip interna y en modo produccion tome el domain ( y protocolo https ) de donde esté alojado el server.js q sirve el path `/send-email`. x ejemplo `private apiUrl = environment.apiHost + 'send-email';  // URL to web api`

Comment: 2/ los archivos de entorno son x lo general `./src/environments/environment.prod.ts` y `./src/environments/environment.ts` en cada uno podes definir un `apiHost` diferente ( tb podes generar otros entornos onda alpha, beta, qa1, qa2 etc cada uno apuntando a un branch de code o una version de api )

Comment: @aloMalbarez te agradezco mucho por esa idea... no tengo cancha en lo q es Backend de Angular, por eso no sabia eso de los environments en el framework

Eso solucionaría mi problema de Protocolos http y https??? 

De mi Frontend de Angular en plesk estoy mandando a un IIS que tiene el .js

Comment: en realidad no es tanto backend, angular es solo frontend. se le llama environment vars pero no las toma del environment sino q se compilan junto al resto del js ( internamente al compilar/transpilar se intercambian los archivos de config segun el target :  `ng build --prod` replaces `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts`). esas vars estan disponibles en el frontend si queres hacer algo mas tipo compilar y al desplegar ( copiar el html + javascript fronted al servidor web) te tome la config "automagicamente" podes poner las vars en el html onda https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/603619/81450

Comment: @aloMalbarez Claro, entiendo. Mi problema es en si en que no tengo conocimiento claro de cómo "desplegar" mi backend que tiene el server.js 
como es la primera vez que hago esto estoy aprendiendo a los golpes, una alternativa que se me ocurrió es instalar IISNode en mi servidor de windows, pero todavia no le encuentro la vuelta porque al subirlo como una aplicación web me larga el error de "Cannot / Get" en el navegador...

El frontend de Angular está funcionando perfecto, mi problema es encontrar el "lugar" en donde poner mi backend p enviar mails y que el frontend de Angular apunte alli